# Compare NSDecimalNumber to NSNumber gets wrong result

Tags: ios, objective-c, nsnumber, nsdecimalnumber

The code is simple and you can reproduce it.

```
NSDecimalNumber *d1 = [NSDecimalNumber decimalNumberWithString:@"6560601600245628933"];
BOOL res = [d1 isEqualToNumber:@(6560601600245628934)];
NSLog(@"%@", @(res));
```

`isEqualToNumber:` always returns `YES`, even I compare `d1` to other numbers like `@6560601600245628930`... Any ideas? Is it a bug ?

Comment: I think a comparison is being made between the object's types here. Try the number 6560601600245.

Comment: It appears to be a precision issue when comparing an `NSNumber` and `NSDecimalNumber`. You get the correct result if both values are `NSDecimalNumber`. You get the correct result with your current code if the number has one less digit in it.

Comment: Sorry, I meant your current code is fine if the numbers have 3 less digits. This means it works with 16 digits but not more. This is essentially the precision of a `double` so it would seem that when comparing an `NSNumber`, the comparison is made with the values as a `double`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Analysis**

`NSDecimalNumber`'s `compare:` (which is called by `isEqualToNumber:`) checks for its argument (`@(6560601600245628934)` here) being another `NSDecimalNumber` and if not resorts to `NSNumber`'s `compare:`  (`NSNumber` being `NSDecimalNumber`'s superclass).

As an `NSNumber` `d1` reports its type as `double` – that is `CFNumberGetType()` returns `kCFNumberDoubleType` – and given a `double` `NSNumber`'s `compare:` compares the two values as `double`.

Your first value (`decimalNumberWithString:@"6560601600245628933"`) is stored without precious loss as an `NSDecimalNumber`, but has more significant digits than a `double` and the conversion loses precision.

Your second value (`@(6560601600245628934)`) is stored by `NSNumber` as a 64-bit integer (`kCFNumberSInt64Type`) without precision loss, but when converted to double loses precision.

With the variations you've tried both numbers when represented as `double` are the same.

**Workaround**

Change:

```
@(6560601600245628934)
```

to:

```
[NSDecimalNumber numberWithLongLong:6560601600245628934LL]
```

to create an `NSDecimalNumber` value directly from your integer. This will result in both arguments to `isEqualToNumber:` being `NSDecimalNumber` and no precision will be lost doing the comparison.

**Bug or feature?**

It might be classed as a *documentation* bug in that I haven't found it documented anywhere (which is far from conclusive!) that the comparison will be done with `double`s. Submit a bug report at [bugreport.apple.com](http://bugreport.apple.com) and see what they say.